# What's the purpose of the fileapifromapp.h API?

Tags: winapi, uwp

There's a set of 11 functions in the *fileapifromapp.h* SDK header file. The supporting documentation lacks information on why that API exists, or which specific problem it addresses. Take [`CreateFileFromAppW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapifromapp/nf-fileapifromapp-createfilefromappw) as an example, whose documented purpose is:

> Creates or opens a file or I/O device. The behavior of this function is identical to [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew), except that this function adheres to the Universal Windows Platform app security model.

So, it's like `CreateFile`, but can be used from a UWP application. That's not entirely confusing. What *is* confusing is, that that's exactly what [`CreateFile2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfile2), introduced in Windows 8, was supposed to accomplish. So why do we have 2 APIs now that apparently solve the same problem?

The documentation of `CreateFileFromAppW` doesn't reference the documentation of `CreateFile2` to explain how it is different, nor vice versa. I can't seem to find an answer to these questions:

- Why did Windows 10 1803 introduce `CreateFileFromAppW` when we already had `CreateFile2` since Windows 8?
- Does `CreateFileFromAppW` offer different functionality compared to `CreateFile2`?

Comment: Rob Caplan [addressed this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a69503ba-e0f6-4060-a43e-d273785a18a0/uwpcbroadfilesystemaccess-and-win32-api-for-uwp?forum=wpdevelop), it is related to the added broadFileSystemAccess capability.  Which is brokered by the Windows::Storage api but not the winapi.  CreateFileFromApp solves that.

Comment: @HansPassant Link is broken :(

Comment: @Neme see https://web.archive.org/web/20220612110854/https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a69503ba-e0f6-4060-a43e-d273785a18a0/uwpcbroadfilesystemaccess-and-win32-api-for-uwp?forum=wpdevelop