# UWP winrt/C++: Save File to external drive with std::ofstream (permission problems)

Tags: c++, uwp, file-permissions, hololens, c++-winrt

**Situation:**

Currently I'm developping an application to save sensor data from Hololens2 to an attached external SSD (via USB-C).
I have sucesfully applied the standard functions of the winrt API [StorageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder?view=winrt-22621) and [StorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile?view=winrt-22621).
Do to large memory consumption and high frame rates, I can not use the provided functions from the api in an Async manner (applied the `.get()` function). Furthermore after some investigations on the file creation time, I observed file creation times between 100-200ms (just create the new empty file!). Writing to the file is arround 10-20ms (depends on size). Preferably, I like to use the standard [std::basic_ofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) which seems to be much faster. My problem is, I can't create a file on my external drive with [std::basic_ofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream). I suspect the problem in the write permissions.

**What I've tried so far**

- Write to `ApplicationData::Current().LocalFolder()` [Sucessfull]:

  I'm able to create and write a file to the LocalAppData Folder with [std::basic_ofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)
- Add the broadFileSystemAccess to the Package.appxmanifest file and activate the filesytem permission in Options->Privacy->Filesystem -> activate my app to give access [NO EFFECT]

  ```
  <Package xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap2 uap3 rescap">
  ```

  ```
  <Capabilities>
      ...
      <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
      ...
  </Capabilities>
  ```

  I have check the given capability with following code sniped and got returned a 4:

  ```
  winrt::Windows::Security::Authorization::AppCapabilityAccess::AppCapability acap = winrt::Windows::Security::Authorization::AppCapabilityAccess::AppCapability::Create(L"broadFileSystemAccess");

  Logger::GetInstance().LogString(L"AppCapability: " + winrt::to_hstring((uint16_t)acap.CheckAccess()));
  ```
- Picked the external drive with [FolderPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker?view=winrt-22621) and add the picked folder (root folder of the SSD) to the [StorageApplicationPermissions::FutureAccessList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions?view=winrt-22621) [NO EFFECT]

Has someone a solution to my problem?

How can I grant basic write access to my external drive?

I'm also open to use other functions than [std::basic_ofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream). They should be faster than the provided ones of the winrt API and Non-asynchronous.

Comment: You'll probably want to use [`CreateFileFromAppW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapifromapp/nf-fileapifromapp-createfilefromappw) to create a file with the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability. Once you have a handle to a newly created file you can use `WriteFile` to write to it.

Comment: Thanks! Thats it :) and much faster also. P.S I Tried also CreateFile2FromAppW and there the file was not created.

Comment: @IInspectable I think you could convert your comment as answer since it helps solve the issue.

Comment: I would, if I understood this topic sufficiently well. As it turns out, I'm [just as confused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72586123/1889329).

Answer (score 1):

The basic thing to remember about UWP apps is that they do NOT have rights to most of the file system or many other devices. For example, they have READ ONLY access to the package folder, READ/WRITE access to a temporary location, READ/WRITE access to a local per-user/per-app folder location and that's about it.

While running, the USER can provide a file to such a UWP app the File Picker which uses a "broker" to give UWP app temporary permission. In the case of File Picker, however, the object handed back could be a file on the local disk, on a remote system, or through some other mechanism. The Windows Runtime APIs can use these objects directly, but the traditional C/C++ I/O functions will not. The C/C++ Runtime uses `CreateFile2` in the implementation, and this function can only open local files with the access rights above, not through a 'broker'.

If your parsing code is using C/C++ I/O functions, then you need to do use Windows Runtime APIs to copy the file to a temp location and THEN use the C/C++ code to read it.

```
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h"

using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers;

FileOpenPicker openPicker;
openPicker.ViewMode(PickerViewMode::Thumbnail);
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation(PickerLocationId::PicturesLibrary);
openPicker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".jpg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".png");

auto file = co_await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file)
{
    auto tempFolder = ApplicationData::Current().TemporaryFolder();
    auto tempFile = co_await file.CopyAsync(tempFolder, file.Name(), NameCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName);
    if (tempFile)
    {
        // Use your C/C++ code to readtempFile.Path()
        DeleteFile(tempFile.Path().c_str());
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr);
    }
}
```

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

> `CreateFileFromApp` and `CreateFile2FromApp` can be used to use Win32 style I/O functions directly on a 'brokered' file. It first attempts to open the file using traditional `CreateFile` / `CreateFile2` and if it fails, it  tries to use a 'brokered' version if the application has rights to the resource.

> The C/C++ Runtime uses `CreateFile2` instead of `CreateFile2FromApp` because the 'fromapp' API wasn't introduced until Windows 10 Version 1803. There's discussion of how/when the C+/C++ Runtime might use this API on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1210).